# docker size is become too big after I commit

Tags: docker

When I commit the docker image it become 60G size.

 so I tired to minimize the docker size then I delete some files inside of the docker

 after that I recommit the image but it become bigger....

 1. which space is affect to the docker commit size?

 2. how should I minimize the size of the docker after I commit?

Comment: are you using any volume in the docker file ? please post your file and/or provide further information

Comment: just in case. you can exclude files within dockerignore file

Comment: You should probably _never_ run `docker commit`.  How do I reproduce this very large image so I can understand your problem?  If there's a security issue in the original image and I need to update that image, how can I recreate the image?

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesn't just store the final state of the image. It stores every *change* you make. So if you add a 1 GB file, and then immediately delete it, it will add 2 GB to the size even though you have 0 GB of files. (I think in practice this example will be less than 2 GB because they compress it, but you get the idea)

If you want to keep your Docker images small, you should create as few files as possible. Don't add a 1 GB file if you will delete it later, just don't add it in the first place.

If you really need to create and delete a large file, the trick is to do it in a single layer. That means you have to do a single Docker command. You can do things like `RUN ./create_big_file.sh && ./do_something.sh && rm big_file.bin`. Or you can write a script like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

./create_big_file.sh
./do_something.sh
rm big_file.bin
```

and then in your Dockerfile do:

```
COPY my_script.sh
RUN ./my_script.sh
```